# Count number of occurences of a character in an element using xquery

Tags: count, xquery, osb

I have a variable which has `|` separated values like below.

I need to make sure it never has more than 30 sequences separated by `'|'`, so i believe if i count number of occurrences of `'|'` in the var it would suffice

```
class=1111|2222|3333|4444
```

Can you please help in writing `xquery` for the same.

I am new to `xquery`.

Comment: It’s difficult for me to understand what are your exact requirements. Could you please add a self-contained example (XML, XQuery) that gives us insight into the “variable” and the “sequences”, and that shows what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

If you remove all characters but the bar and then use string-length as in `let $s := '1111|2222|3333|4444' return string-length(translate($s, translate($s, '|', ''), ''))` you get the number of `|` characters. That use of string-length and the double translate to remove anything but a certain character is an old XPath 1 trick, of course as XQuery also has `replace` you could as well use `let $s := '1111|2222|3333|4444' return string-length(replace($s, '[^|]+', ''))`.

Comment: +1 for the universally applicable 1.0 or greater solution. `translate()` is character based, which avoids any potential confusion with regex escaping and is likely to be a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-tokenize) function to split the value by the `|` character, and then count how many items in the sequence with [`fn:count()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-count).

Just remember that the tokenize function uses a regex pattern, so you would need to escape the `|` as `\|`:

```
let $PSV := "1111|2222|3333|4444"

let $tokens := fn:tokenize($PSV, "\|")
let $token-count := fn:count($tokens)
return
  if ($token-count > 30) then
    fn:error((), "Too many pipe separated values")
  else
    (: less than thirty values, do stuff with the $tokens :)
    ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for good measure, and in case you want to do any performance comparisons, you could try

```
let $sep := string-to-codepoints('|')
return count(string-to-codepoints($in)[.=$sep])
```

This has the theoretical advantage that (at least in Saxon) it doesn't construct any new strings or sequences in memory.